# Linux Document about tracepoint

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In Ubuntu (or else linux system), there are some directory in /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events, but I don't know what these directory mean. For example, /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_bio_backmerge, I want some documents to describe this what they mean. Can u give me some relevant documents or some other advice to learn.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get by google, like [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/trace/events.html). And the [brendangregg's blog](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-06-29/perf-static-tracepoints.html) is really deserve to read.